# How to set relative paths with respect to upper subdirectories in CMakeList.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, relative-path

I am modifying a CMakeLists.txt to compile a library with dependencies. I'm confused how to provide relative paths to locations which are in subdirectories above `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`. Normally, I would use `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` to create relative paths, or use the absolute path. The latter isn't an option here.

Here's my situation:

Using CMakeLists.txt, it currently cannot find the other libraries (here, `FIRST`, `SECOND`, and `THIRD`) via

```
find_package(FIRST REQUIRED)
find_package(SECOND REQUIRED)
```

So, I would like to set the include/lib paths via:

```
FIRST_INCLUDE_DIR=
FIRST_LIBRARY=
SECOND_INCLUDE_DIR=
SECOND_LIBRARY=
```

Currently, for the full directory of the listfile currently being processed, the following

```
message("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")
```

outputs

/home/travis/build/repohandle/libraryname/00_pkg_src/libraryname/src/package

However, the locations for `FIRST` and `SECOND` are here:

```
/home/travis/build/repohandle/libraryname/00_pkg_src/libraryname/src/first
/home/travis/build/repohandle/libraryname/00_pkg_src/libraryname/src/second
```

How could I link to `/src/first` and `/src/second` using a relative path?

Something like:

```
FIRST_INCLUDE_DIR="${SOME_LOCATION}/src/first/include"
FIRST_LIBRARY="${SOME_LOCATION}/src/first/"
SECOND_INCLUDE_DIR="${SOME_LOCATION}/src/second/include"
SECOND_LIBRARY="${SOME_LOCATION}/src/second/include"
```

Comment: Where is your `CMakeLists.txt` file located? `src/package`? I'm not sure I understand your build tree. Probably something like `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../first")` would help.

Comment: @Florian What is the difference between `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ..) ` and `set(FIRST_INCLUDE_DIR ..)`? This may be the source of my confusion

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: Aside the first command add value(s) to the list, represented by a variable, and the second one sets complete value of the variable, these two commands affects **different variables**. Probably, Florian meant `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, which means a list of **install directories** of the searched packages, not `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` which affects search of CMake scripts (`.cmake` files).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the help. It's odd---appending to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` alone meant that the packages were not found via `find_package()`. If I explicitly set each to the variables above, the packages are listed as found via `find_package()`. I'm not sure what to make of this

Comment: It fully depends on `FindFIRST.cmake` and `FindSECOND.cmake` scripts used for find the packages.

Comment: @Tsyvarev (1) I think the set variable approach cannot be right, as I'm setting the variables to a subdirectory. (2) I'm not sure what you mean by "It fully depends on FindFIRST.cmakes". Could you provide more details?

Comment: CMake doesn't search packages (their libraries and include directories) by its own. It could be `FindXXX.cmake` script which helps to locate `XXX` package. For some packages, such scripts are shipped with [CMake installation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-modules.7.html), for find other packages, scripts should be shipped with your package, which uses other package(s). More info see on `find_package` [documentation page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html), "Module" mode.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh, I understand now. These are the scripts written by the user (me) which helps find the package in question. In these scripts, I used (as an example) `FIRST_PKGCONF_INCLUDE_DIRS`. It's here I should try explicitly finding all the libraries/headers, correct?

Comment: No, you shouldn't change those scripts. But a way how they search things affects on a way of helping them in that search. Because you don't show those scripts to use, we can only guess how to help you. *Usually* variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` works. But it may do not work in some scripts.